# How to configure a custom filter programatically in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

On user authentication i need to retrieve his remote address and remote host.
I'm trying to implement a custom filter to support this, but i'm getting "**authenticationManager must be specified**".
Another doubt is... What is the correct way to register a custom filter using programmatically ?

Configuration using annotations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityApplicationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private SCAAuthenticationFilter scaAuthenticationFilter;

  @Autowired
  private SCAAuthenticationProvider scaAuthenticationProvider;

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(scaAuthenticationProvider);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .addFilter(scaAuthenticationFilter) // What is the right way ?
      .addFilterBefore(scaAuthenticationFilter, AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class) // What is the right way ?
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/manual/**").authenticated()
        .and()
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/manual")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
      .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and();
  }
}
```

The custom filter:

```
@Component
public class SCAAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (!request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
      throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
    }
    String username = obtainUsername(request);
    String password = obtainPassword(request);
    String remoteHost = request.getRemoteHost();
    String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
    if (username == null) {
      username = "";
    }
    if (password == null) {
      password = "";
    }
    username = username.trim();
    SCAAuthenticationToken scaAuthenticationToken = new SCAAuthenticationToken(username, password, remoteHost, remoteAddr);
    setDetails(request, scaAuthenticationToken);
    return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(scaAuthenticationToken);
  }

}
```

Comment: The `addFilter` and `addFilterBefore` behaviour should be pretty clear from the [Javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html).

Comment: Yes, the filter is called but it's occurs "authenticationManager must be specified". I don't know how to set the authentication manager. I try with @Autowired authenticationManager but doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You need set a authenticationManagerBean for your extended filter and config it corr

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter()
            throws Exception {
        ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter = new ExUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
        exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
                .setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        RequestMatcher requestMatcher = new RequestMatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
                if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().indexOf("/api", 0) >= 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

        http
                .addFilterBefore(exUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your custom filter extends Spring Security's `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, which means it needs a reference to the authentication manager. I would create your filter as an `@Bean` in the security configuration, then follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19814105/241990) which explains different options for getting a reference to the `AuthenticationManager`.

Comment: Can you post an example here ?

Comment: I managed to add the filter with an instance of authenticationmanager, but on login, the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is also used and it's accurring nullpointer.

Answer (score 1):

In the class that is extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, override the authenticationManagerBean() method and annotate it with @Bean as such:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class YourCustomConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
```

Now you will be able to @Autowire the AuthenticationManager in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a configurer for your filter and delegate all the work concerning filter initialization to it (the same way `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is configured through the `FormLoginConfigurer` and `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` is configured by the `AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer`).

```
public class SCAAuthenticationConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>() {

    public static SCAAuthenticationConfigurer scaAuthentication() {
        return new SCAAuthenticationConfigurer()
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        SCAAuthenticationFilter filter = new SCAAuthenticationFilter()
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class));

        // add postProcess(filter) call if require to autowire some fields

        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    }
}
```

Having such configurer your `SecurityConfig` will be looking more tidy:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .apply(scaAuthentication())
            .and()

            // do the rest of configuration
    }
}
```

You may even delegate filter initialization to the ApplicationContext (for example, if you have configuration to inject):

```
public class FilterWithSettingsConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity>() {

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeSettings.class)
    private static class Config {}

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()
        context.parent = http.getSharedObject(ApplicationContext.class)
        context.register(Config.class)
        context.refresh()

        FilterWithSettings filter = 
            context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(FilterWithSettings.class)

        filter.setAuthenticationManager(http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class));

        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    }
}
```

For the comprehensive example take a look at the https://github.com/shiver-me-timbers/smt-spring-security-parent/blob/master/smt-spring-security-jwt/src/main/java/shiver/me/timbers/spring/security/JwtSpringSecurityAdaptor.java