# AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter is not firing before UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

Hi to all Spring Experts!

I have an issue that I'm trying to solve for a while but i think that i have reached a dead end.

So basically what I need, is to configure my Spring-Security (in Spring-Boot) to have two authentication mechanisms (one for Legacy JSP pages and one for REST APIs). So I followed the following post:
[multiple authentication mechanisms in a single app using java config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794680/multiple-authentication-mechanisms-in-a-single-app-using-java-config)

It worked fine with one LDAP authentication provider. But then I tried to extend my LDAP connection to also obtain a ticket from a third party service (that will be used for future connections to other services), and there I had a problem.

So I created a new Authentication Token, Filter and Authentication provider, but the default `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` is being fired first, no matter what I do.

I tried to follow this post [How to configure a custom filter programatically in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810846/how-to-configure-a-custom-filter-programatically-in-spring-security) and saw that the problem might be in the fact that my filter was extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. So I removed this and tried to have a simple `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, still - no luck.

I think the problem is in my WebSecurity configuration. Currently, with the following code I'm gonna share, the REST Api authentication is returning **405 - method not allowed** and the legacy Login is stuck in an infinite loop and crashes, even before I hit "Login".

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) //Enables @PreAuthorize on methods
public class WebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private LDAPConfigurationBean ldapBean;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//HERE GOES LDAP CONNECTION STUFF               
//      Add the custom LDAP + Token provider to the Authentication provider chain
        auth.authenticationProvider(new TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationProvider(authenticator,authoritiesPopulator));

//        Creating an LDAP provider using the authenticator and the populator.
        auth.authenticationProvider(new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authenticator,authoritiesPopulator));

    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ConfigureFilters extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.addFilterBefore(new TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }
    }

    //Management Endpoints Authorization
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class EndpointsWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/manage/health")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
    }

    //API Authentication+Authorization
    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
        @Autowired
        private RestAuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;
        @Autowired
        private RestAuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;
        @Autowired
        private RestLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

        private String LOGIN_PATH = "/api/authenticate";
        private String USERNAME = "username";
        private String PASSWORD = "password";

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            /*CSRF configuration*/
            http.csrf().disable();

            http
                    .antMatcher(LOGIN_PATH)
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();

            http
                    .antMatcher("/api/**")
                    //Stateless session creation - no session will be created or used by Spring Security
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().permitAll()
                        .loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PATH)
                        .usernameParameter(USERNAME)
                        .passwordParameter(PASSWORD)
                        .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                        .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll()
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);

            http
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    //JSP Authentication+Authorization
    @Configuration
    @Order(4)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            /*CSRF configuration*/
            http.csrf().disable();

            /*Static content*/
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/css*//**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/images*//**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/scripts*//**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/fonts*//**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/login*").anonymous();

        /*Login / Logout configuration*/
            http
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login.htm").permitAll()
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.htm?name=******")
                        .failureUrl("/login.htm?error=true")
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll()
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.htm")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        /*URL roles authorizations*/
            http
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to configure my filter in the "Configure Filters" method - but I have also tried to configure it inside the adapters, with / without a `@Bean` annotation - all with no luck.

Filter:

```
public class TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationFilter  extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    public TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationFilter() {
        super("/*");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        //Save the password for later
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationToken token = new TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationToken(username,password,null);

        return token;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** forgot to add to the filter:

```
if ( request.getParameter( "username" ) == null || request.getParameter( "password" ) == null ) == null ) {
            return null;
        }
```

Now I get 405 in both login mechanisms.

Token:

```
public class TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationToken  extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    private AuthTicket otp;
    private String restoredPassword;


    public TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationToken( String username, String password, RestAuthLoginTicket otp ) {
        super( username, password );
        this.otp = otp;
    }

    public AuthTicket getOTP() {
        return otp;
    }

    public AuthTicket getOtp() {
        return otp;
    }

    public void setOtp(AuthTicket otp) {
        this.otp = otp;
    }
}
```

Provider:

```
public class TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationProvider extends LdapAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    TokenUtils tokenUtils;

    public TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationProvider(LdapAuthenticator authenticator, LdapAuthoritiesPopulator authoritiesPopulator) {
        super(authenticator, authoritiesPopulator);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
              TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationToken token =  (TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationToken) super.authenticate(authentication);
        token.setOtp(tokenUtils.getTicket(token));
        return token;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the issue(s).

First of all, the right way to configure the authentication managers is not how I configured above because there is no `antMatcher` and this caused my resources and pages to be open to everybody.

Secondly, the problem that caused the infinite redirects and error 405 was that I haven't defined my filter to accept post.

After fixing that, my JSP login form and authentication mechanism worked fine, but the "/api" was redirecting to the login page instead of the resource.

What brings me to my final point - the `http.formLogin()` is creating a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. I have two of them - one for each login. So I had to add `http.addFilterBefore()` for each one of the logins, but with a different URL.
The "/api" url was again using the default redirects of Spring instead of what I have defined, so I had to override them.

These are the configurations and filters that are working for me:

Security Configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) //Enables @PreAuthorize on methods
public class WebSecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private LDAPConfigurationBean ldapBean;

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        //LDAP Stuff

        TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationProvider ticketAndLDAPAuthenticationProvider = new TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationProvider(authenticator,authoritiesPopulator);
        auth.authenticationProvider(ticketAndLDAPAuthenticationProvider);

        LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authenticator,authoritiesPopulator);
        auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider);    
    }

    //Management Endpoints Authorization
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class EndpointsWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .antMatcher("/manage/health")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
    }

    //API Authentication+Authorization
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;
        @Autowired
        private RestAuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;
        @Autowired
        private RestAuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;
        @Autowired
        private RestLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

        private String LOGIN_PATH = "/api/authenticate";

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            /*CSRF configuration*/
            http.csrf().disable();

            http.addFilterBefore(new TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationFilter(LOGIN_PATH,authSuccessHandler,authFailureHandler), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

            http
                    .antMatcher("/api/**")
//                    Stateless session creation - no session will be created or used by Spring Security
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll()
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler);

            http
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

        }
    }

    //JSP Authentication+Authorization
    @Configuration
    @Order(3)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private String LOGIN_PATH = "/login.htm";

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            /*CSRF configuration*/
            http.csrf().disable();

            http.addFilterBefore(new TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationFilter(LOGIN_PATH), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

            /*Static content*/
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/css*//**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/images*//**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/scripts*//**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/fonts*//**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/login*").anonymous();

        /*Login / Logout configuration*/
            http
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage(LOGIN_PATH).permitAll()
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.htm?name=******")
                        .failureUrl("/login.htm?error=true")
                    .and()
                    .logout().permitAll()
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.htm")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        /*URL roles authorizations*/
            http
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Filter:

```
public class TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationFilter  extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationFilter(String defaultProcessUrl) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(defaultProcessUrl, "POST"));
    }

    public TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationFilter(String defaultProcessUrl, AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(defaultProcessUrl, "POST"));
        setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        //Save the password for later
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if ( username==null || password==null) {
            return null;
        }

        TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationToken token = new TicketAndLDAPAuthenticationToken(username,password,null);

        return token;
    }
}
```